# Parsing xml doc with XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse this xml doc using XDocument, but not understanding how to extract the data from the inner bolts of the XDocument.

the nodes look like this:

```
<data name="GetOrdersMailMsg" xml:space="preserve">
<value>
        SELECT Orders.buyersEmail,
            Orders.emailMessage
            FROM Orders
            WHERE Orders.orderId = '{0}'
    </value>
<comment>Get email message(s) to buyer</comment>
</data>
<data name="UpdateOrdersMailMsg" xml:space="preserve">
<value>
        UPDATE Orders
            SET    Orders.buyersEmail = '{0}',
                    Orders.emailMessage = '{1}'
            WHERE Orders.orderId = '{2}'
    </value>
<comment>Update mail message to buyer</comment>
</data>
```

I need the "value", the "comment" and "data name" for each  node. I am trying the code below:

```
                xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

                //Get all nodes
                List<XNode> xNodes = xdoc.DescendantNodes().ToList();
                foreach (XNode node in xNodes)
                {
                    XElement element = node as XElement;

                    if (null != element)
                    {
                        //For each orderProperty, get all attributes
                        foreach (XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
                        {
                            string name = attribute.Name.ToString();
                            string value = attribute.Value.ToString();

                            Debug.WriteLine("name:" + name);
                            Debug.WriteLine("value:" + value);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but it is not giving what I want. Anyone can point me out how to get the data I need?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is missing a root and therefore no XML actually. But I assume you just didn't post it.

You can use `Elements()` on the root element searching for all elements called `data`. From them you can get the `name` attribute with `Attribute()` and the `value` element with `Element()`.

```
foreach (XElement xElement in xDocument.Root.Elements("data"))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("name:" + xElement.Attribute("name").Value.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("value:" + xElement.Element("value").Value.ToString());
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/izDp5x)

Comment: that works, thank you. I also need to add xElement.Element("comment").Value.ToString() to get the comment.